# Вопрос по форме-калькулятору

Tags: forms, javascript, php

Добрый день.

Есть форма калькулятор. С отправкой по email.

Есть три текстовых поля, в которых отображается три цены, есть три радиокнопки, которые нужно связать с этими полями.

Если короче: калькулятор посчитал для человека 3 цены, за 45, 60 и 90 минут. Человек должен выбрать выбрать одну кнопку, которая на почту должна передать цена за 45, 60 или 90 мин.

Из одного параметра value цифры должны передаваться в другой и отправляться на почту.

Comment: пожалуйста, напишите с чем именно или на каком этапе выполнения задания у вас возникли трудности

Comment: Вот есть три текстовых поля 
<input type="text" name="m45" value="0" />
<input type="text" name="m60" value="0" />
<input type="text" name="m90" value="0" />
Их значение value появляется после подсчета калькулятора. 

Есть три радиокнопки. Выбранная кнопка отправляется на почту. 
<input type='radio' name='chb[]' value="0" />45 Минут
<input type='radio' name='chb[]' value="0" />60 Минут
<input type='radio' name='chb[]' value="0" />90 Минут

Мне нужно значение текстового поля, чтобы отображалось в радиокнопке. Чтобы при выборе кнопки, отправлялась только одна цена из трех.

Comment: Где то читал что нужно рыть в сторону onchange="" можете пояснить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно по вопросу, начните [отсюда](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_value.asp). А [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) про onchange...

**upd** Отлично, что делаете сами. Серьезно.

For radio buttons, the contents of the value property do not appear in the user interface. The value property only has meaning when submitting a form. **If a radio button is in checked state when the form is submitted, the name of the radio button is sent along with the value of the value property** (if the radio button is not checked, no information is sent).

Все три и не будут посылаться. Это же radio, имя у них одно, значит будет посылаться то, значение, которое выбрано. Укажите значение для радиокнопки и все.

**upd2**. еще раз перечитал комментарий. value, которое считается у вас и вы его пишите в `input type="text"`'ы пишите в значения этих радио кнопок. Для radio кнопок надо установить соответствие с ценами. задайте для них id, например:

```
<input type="radio" name="chb[]" id="r45" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="chb[]" id="r60" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="chb[]" id="r90" value="0">
```

при подсчете пишите в них соответствующие значения в скрипте:

```
document.getElementById('r45').value = 1000;
document.getElementById('r60').value = 1500;
document.getElementById('r90').value = 2000;
```

при отправке формы, на сервере ловите то, что записано в chb[], там будет выбранная цена.

Comment: Подозрение не оправдалось. 

Форма самописная, за меня я делать не прошу. Все работает уже. Я лишь хочу сделать чтобы посылалась только выбранная цена. А не все три.

Comment: Так-с тут непонятки. 

И судя по ответу, вы кажется меня поняли наоборот. По вашей конструкции при нажатии на радиокнопку в текстовом поле должно появлятся 1000,1500,2000.

А надо чтобы из трех текстовых полей отправлялось то которое я выбрал, посредтством радиокнопки.

Вот эта форма http://aubakirovalexandr.com/index.php

Comment: все верно. у вас тестовых полях выводится значение для пользователя. а на сервер надо отправлять то, что в radio прописано, так будет логичнее.
[ваша форма][1]. подправил чуть-чуть html, добавил ``<label>`` для радокнопок.

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/Pk4A4/

Comment: Все, работает. Огромное спасибо.

Comment: Если не затруднить, можете сказать, возможно ли передать с цифровым значением и value="" радиокнопки которую нажали. чтобы допустим "Цена 5000р За 90 минут "          <input type="radio" name="chb[]" id="r90" value="За 90 минут">

Comment: Конечно, value, которое задается для радио-кнопки, меняйте как вам надо...